# SharePoint 2016 - Azure - Work after open site on vm - The server could not save the form at this time. Try Again

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, error, azure

I'm trying to solve a little problem.
I have a **SharePoint 2016** on a vm **Azure** and if I connect to my site on port 80 I have this following problem when I want insert item on a **custom list**:

*"The server could not save the form at this time. Try Again"*

[image]

In network I can see this error : 
ProcessQuery
/_vti_bin/client.svc
Status Code: 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

If I connect to remote desktop (with rdp), I don't have problem to insert item into the list.

If I leave my vm (I connect to my site before leave it), and if I reconnect on the site I can insert an item ....

The memory is good, anonymous connections is enabled.
I am a little lost. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options:

1. In SP 2013/2016 if your list has unique permissions and a user/group has permissions only on that list and has limited or no access at the site level, then you run into this error: "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."
   This can be resolved by either giving that user/group at least read access at the site level
2. Perform an IISReset
3. Sometimes Search Host Controller Service apparently is gobbling up all the memory on the WFE. Once restarted you can now save the list items
4. Also try- Machine restart that might fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but event if I perform a IIS or restrart search Host Controller service or a restart, It doesn't work :(

if I go on the machine virtual (on azure) and I lauch my site on : mySite.com/Lists/Init/NewForm.aspx -> it's ok for adding list item

After, if I go outside the VM on : mySite.com/Lists/Init/NewForm.aspx -> it's ok for adding list item

If I restart my VM and I go outside the VM mySite.com/Lists/Init/NewForm.aspx -> KO

Answer (score 0):

I try to create document library outside my Azure VM.
Upload document : OK
[image]

Edit Properies : KO

[image]

I don't understand why a different authentication process look necessary for edit it.